# owl carousel navigation deffect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, owl-carousel

I have an owl carousel,my website is responsive,when I opening my website on iphone I getting this, my owl carousel navigation is cliped but it only for `iphone` on the `samsung` devies website looks fine,on the my computer monitor also looks fine,does anyone know what it is
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set for arrows owl-next and owl-prev more z-index via css

```
.owl-next, .owl-prev {z-index: 90;}
```